# Using different folder names for different deployments of the same repository

Tags: git

On local development, and on the test server,  the public folder is `public_html`, but on production it’s `html`. I’d like to avoid changing too many settings – is there a way for Git to understand these are the same folder?

### Edit

Here’s the structure for reference:

```
Test server
- webapp
    - app
    - core
- public_html
    - index.php

Production server
- webapp
    - app
    - core
- html
    - index.php
```

Comment: Add more detail on your setup - is `html` a repo or a folder within a repo or just the working copy?

Comment: Why you dont just rename the folder in your local environment?

Comment: The name of the folder containing your project and its git repository is not significant to git.

Comment: Sorry guys, didn’t explain properly, Git lives above `public_html` because it’s a webapp with folders above `public_html`.

Comment: you need to show the structure of your solution and what technology you are using.

Comment: I’ve added the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic links would save the day, assuming a sane platform.  Git can store the symbolic link.

I'd have the symbolic link be the dev/test server name, not the production name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a smudge/clean script to move the files to the place you want on your dev machine. When your working tree is updated, the files are "smudged" so they come out as public_html/somefile.html. When you commit changes, the tree that gets saved will be "cleaned" and the files will be stored as public/somefile.html.

[image]
[image]

More on this here:

http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html

Hope this helps